# How do I replace the division text with “Copied!” after clicked using clipboard.js and make it disappear after a couple of seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard.js

I want the text of the 'div' to change to "copied!" for only a couple of seconds and get back the original text after that particular time period.

This is a sample of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body

<div class="row">

    <div class="box col-xs-2 btn red1 integration-checklist__copy-button" id="#E44236" data-clipboard-text="#E44236"><p>#E44236</p></div>
    <script>
        var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');

        clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
            e.clearSelection();
            e.trigger.textContent = 'Copied!';
        });

        clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
            console.info(e);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to achieve this. The code below runs the "timer" function 1000 milliseconds after you've copied the text. Feel free to change that value to whatever you prefer.

```
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.btn');

clipboard.on('success', function (e) {
    e.clearSelection();
    e.trigger.textContent = 'Copied!';

    var interval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    function timer() {
        e.trigger.textContent = e.text;
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});

clipboard.on('error', function (e) {
    console.info(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using jquery setTimeout as follows:

```
  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    $(e.trigger).text("Copied!");
    e.clearSelection();
    setTimeout(function() {

//let x = get the original text for this control and reset again after some time    
$(e.trigger).text("original text");
    }, 2500);}
```

we can also use jquery show hide fadeout methods like:

```
var clip = new Clipboard('.btn');
clip.on('success', function(e) {
    $('.copied').show();
    $('.copied').fadeOut(1000);
});
```